# Twin notch filter working

Tags: filter, active-filter, filtering

Can someone please explain to me in depth as to how this twin notch circuit is working. Also is what is the formula for finding the notch frequency  because some sites give the answer as (1/2×pi×RC) while the others as (1/4×pi×RC).
[image: Twin notch filter circuit image]

Comment: does my answer work for you?

Comment: Notice there are some assumptions about the source resistance (to left) and the load resistance (to the right).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is \$ T=RC/2 \$ only if using: {R,R/2 and C,2C}

Of course, using: {R,2R and C,2C} then it is \$T=RC/4\$ **so both are true.**

> Can someone please explain to me in depth as to how this twin notch circuit is working?

It works by superposition of attenuated LPF and HPF causing exact same reduced amplitude and opposite phase cancelling the combined signal.  The output impedance of the HPF also loads the output of LPF and visa-versa and contributes to the response of each.

The notch phase response starts at 0 deg at DC rising to +135' neaR notch then 0 at centre then dropping to -135' ( =-90'-45') with +/-45' shift for each midpoint.

The depth in dB of the notch depends on the external load to be high and the worst case tolerance error of each part.  A worst case random part tolerance of 1%  might reduce the notch to -40 dB and shift the frequency according to T=RC/2 tolerance stackup.

e.g. 60Hz  The depth is limited by the resolution of the step frequency plot with an offset of 0.01 Hz at 60.01 Hz for a 60Hz notch.

[image]
Using a 50 Ohm generator would work except above the notch attenuation occurs based on R ratios.

[image]

Comment: How do you get -40dB out of RC filters?

Comment: In theory with ideal parts the Notch filter is - ∞ from perfect amplitude and phase cancellation

Comment: That would be with no inductors or op-amps?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Thank you for the explanation..I have got a little hang of it but understood a lot..

Comment: I'll read more about it and may get back here..

Comment: My pictures tell a thousand words

Comment: Thank you for your support ! I have now understood it clearly.

Comment: OK there's a quiz now. With 1% parts how deep is the notch worst case??

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75 I just realized that I didn't mark the answers as accepted as I didn't know realize about the option until some user brought it to my attention . And to answer your question it would -40db right!?

Comment: And sorry for replying late cause I didn't get a notification that you had posted a comment. I'm still getting a hang of the things on this site

Comment: 40 dB is possible with 1 or 0.5% parts but your source impedance is not zero like an Op Amp then an active twin T is “mo betta.”